# Why does deriveFont(float size) not change font size in a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jbutton

The `deriveFont(float size)` method just makes the `Font` plain without changing its size.

```
JButton prevButton = new JButton("Previous");
prevButton.setFont(prevButton.getFont().deriveFont(90));
```

If I use deriveFont(int style, float size) like in the following example it works as intended.

```
JButton prevButton = new JButton("Previous");
prevButton.setFont(prevButton.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 90));
```

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the variable arguments of all `deriveFont` overloads. When you `deriveFont(90)`, (someone could say it is kind ambiguous) you are changing the style of the font and not the size. The method is `deriveFont(int style)`, where accepted `style` values are `Font.BOLD`,`Font.ITALIC` and `Font.PLAIN`.

In the other hand, another overload of this method is `deriveFont(float size)`. Note the `float`. In order to make this work you should `deriveFont((float) 90)` or `deriveFont(90f)` as @camickr pointed in comments. Casting the `int` to `float` will make it clear you want to change the size.

Comment: (1+) Or you can use 90.0f.

Comment: @camickr Indeed. Thanks for mentioning it. :)

Comment: Whoever created this interface deserves ... I know not exactly what, but certainly nothing nice. Did then never hear about "principle of least surprise" back in the Stone Age? ;)